# Implementing a RMW operation in Redis

Tags: redis

I would like to maintain comma separated lists of entries of the following form `<ip>:<app>` indexed by a an account ID. There would be one such list for each user indexed by their account ID with the number of users in the millions. This is mainly to track which server in a cluster a user using a certain application is connected to.

Since all servers are written in Java, with Redisson I'm currently doing:

```
RSet<String> set = client.getSet(accountKey);
```

and then I can modify the set using some typical Java container APIs supported by Redisson. I basically need three types of updates to these comma separated lists:

1. Client connects to a new application = append
2. Client reconnects with existing application to new endpoint = modify
3. Client disconnects = remove

A new connection would require a change to a field like:

```
1.1.1.1:foo,2.2.2.2:bar -> 1.1.1.1:foo,2.2.2.2:bar,3.3.3.3:baz
```

A reconnect would require an update like:

```
1.1.1.1:foo,2.2.2.2:bar -> 3.3.3.3:foo,2.2.2.2:bar
```

A disconnect would require an update like:

```
1.1.1.1:foo,2.2.2.2:bar -> 2.2.2.2:bar
```

As mentioned the fields would be keyed by the account ID of the user.

My question is the following: Without using Redisson how can I implement this "directly" on top of Redis commands? The goal is to allow rewriting certain components in a language different than Java. The cluster handles close to a million requests per second.

I'm actually quite curious how Redisson implements an `RSet` under the hood and I haven't had time to dig into it. I guess one option would be to use Lua, but I've never used it with Redis. Any ideas how to efficiently implement these operations on top of Redis on a manner that is easily supported by multiple languages, i.e. not relying on a specific library?

Answer (score 0):

Having actually thought about the problem properly, it can be solved directly with a HSET. Where `<app>` is the field name and the value are the IPs. Keys being user accounts.